# Sqlite C/C++ API - Get timestamp value with select query

Tags: sqlite

I use sqlite3 C/C++ API to retrieve rows from a table using SELECT query. I don't see any sqlite3_column_timestamp() to retrieve a timestamp column value after sqlite3_step().. How to get timestamp values ?

Comment: SQLite doesn't have a timestamp data type, so use whatever type (number or text/string) you used when storing the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite does not have a special timestamp data type.

When you want to use any of SQLite's [date and time functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), you have to store timestamps in one of the [formats supported by them](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), i.e., a string like `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` or `HH:MM:SS`, a julian date number, or a Unix timestamp number.

You can declare a table column type as `DATETIME`, but SQLite will just ignore that type; SQLite always allows to put values of any type in any column. Such a declaration would be useful only as documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The column/value accessors will only have types corresponding to the [data types they support directly](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) (`NULL`, `INTEGER`, `REAL`, `TEXT`, `BLOB`).

You would use the `TEXT` access to get/set the column value of dates.

There are some [helper functions *within* SQL](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) that they provide that let you to handle them in your queries.

I am not familiar with SQLite Manager, but I would assume that it is only reporting the data type that the table was declared with.

When parsing `CREATE` statements, sqlite understands the intention of many well supported datatypes and automatically maps them to what is appropriate for its internal storage structure.  `VARCHAR` would be mapped to `TEXT`, for instance.  I assume the column was declared `DATETIME` and sqlite just internally mapped it to `TEXT`.

Comment: which datatype should I use to store timestamps? I saw a DATETIME type in SQLite Manager.